# Odoo quotation product field missing

Tags: python, odoo, erp, odoo-9

When I try to add products to a quotation, I can't find the "Product" field.

[image]

[image]

Is this a bug? Am I missing something?

Comment: There can be rights issue only nothing else.

Comment: Check user permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I fixed it by unchecking portal in the right user window.